# CSV file does not open correctly on Mac computers

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I am using jackson-dataformat-csv library to generate a csv file but I am cannot open it correctly on Mac Computers. Here is the java code to generate csv, I do not know what I am doing wrong here:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvDownload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {

        User user1 = new User("Cow",25, "xxxxxx@gmail.com","1234567890",
                "Street","Heights","7100",
                "Male","Town");

        User user2 = new User("John",26, "xxxxxxx@gmail.com","+1234567890",
                "Street","Heights","7100",
                "Male","Town");


        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);

        // create mapper and schema
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(User.class).withHeader();
        schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(',');

        // output writer
        ObjectWriter myObjectWriter = mapper.writer(schema);
        File tempFile = new File("users.csv");
        FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new 
        BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, 1024);
        OutputStreamWriter writerOutputStream = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, "UTF-8");
        myObjectWriter.writeValue(writerOutputStream, users);
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"name", "age", "email", "phone_number",
    "physical_address", "postal_address", "postal_code",
    "gender", "city"})
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Age")
    private int age;
    @JsonProperty("Email Address")
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("Phone Number")
    private String phone_number;
    @JsonProperty("Physical Address")
    private String physical_address;
    @JsonProperty("Postal Address")
    private String postal_address;
    @JsonProperty("Postal Code")
    private String postal_code;
    @JsonProperty("Gender")
    private String gender;
    @JsonProperty("City")
    private String city;

    public User(String name, int age, String email, String phone_number, String 
    physical_address, String postal_address, String postal_code, String gender, 
    String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.physical_address = physical_address;
        this.postal_address = postal_address;
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public String getPhysical_address() {
        return physical_address;
    }

    public void setPhysical_address(String physical_address) {
        this.physical_address = physical_address;
    }

    public String getPostal_address() {
        return postal_address;
    }

    public void setPostal_address(String postal_address) {
        this.postal_address = postal_address;
    }

    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

This the code I am using to generate a csv file but does not open right on Mac computers, I do not have issues on windows.
[Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDxVK.jpg)

Comment: Are there any errors? What's not working?

Comment: I do not have any errors but does not open correctly on mac. Columns and rows just collapse... I do not know whether I have answered your question.

Comment: What end of line characters does the CSV have? CSV standard uses CRLF. Depending on the implementation it could be tolerant to other line endings characters. Try converting the line endings and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Torino, Lemme try that, then will get back to you.

Comment: @Daniele Torino, Still does not work. I think it has something to do with the column separator. I am using a character (',') as the column separator, which works just fine with windows machines but no luck for Mac machines.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot. The comma should work by default as it's the default separator according to RFC 4180. Personally, I'd step into the library code to look what exactly is happening, but this might be a bit too complicated for a beginner.

Comment: @Paul The only difference between Win CSV and Mac CSV I can think of is the line separator. So you should investigate on that further. What did you actually change to convert the line separator?

Comment: @WurgspaB I created  three boolean methods that first check the OS/platform and use a line separator based on the active OS. Please see below: if (isWindows()){
            schema = schema.withLineSeparator("\r\n");
        }else if (isMac() || isUnix()){
            schema = schema.withColumnSeparator('\n');
        }

Comment: Can you generate a CSV file on the Mac to see what it is using as column separator and as line separator? This may also be locale dependent.

Comment: IMHO the CSV file is perfectly generated. The problem is that Excel for Mac does not accept the comma as a separator.

Comment: There is no problem with your code and running it on a Mac, I have just done so and can import the file into Excel or open it in a text editor and it's fine.

Comment: I just saw your screenshoot, if you open a csv file like that you need to convert the text to columns. The other option (and better) is to have an empty spreadsheet and then choose File->Import

Comment: @Würgspaß @Paul Concerning the line separator, I recommend to use `schema = schema.withLineSeparator(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` to make sure you have the correct one for your OS.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch or just `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: @Joakim yes there is no problem on the code but the problem is when you try to open a csv file in Mac computer and another I do not want to manually import it.

Comment: @Thomas I will then need a Mac computer to do that because I am currently using windows machine but I asked my friend to test it on Mac machine. Thanks.

Comment: So this is not a programming question but rather about Excel on Mac OS X. This is how csv files behaves on a Mac so I don’t really see anything wrong.

Comment: @Joakim I thought I was doing something wrong on the code that causes the csv file to behaves like this on Mac OS X. and I also thought I would get some suggestions to cater both Windows and Mac OS to open csv file correctly without having to manually do changes.

Comment: I used apache poi and I generated excel file with the "xlsx" extension, it seems to be working on both Mac and Windows. Thank you guys.